# Ruby in 100 Minutes, good_morning method

Tags: ruby, irb, nomethoderror

I have been doing *the Ruby in 100 minutes* website, and encountered a problem during part 5.

I was asked to create a `good_morning` method that would print out a greeting such as  `'Happy Monday, it's the 130 day of 2013'`. Here is my current program:

```
class PersonalChef
def good_morning
    date = Time.new
    today = Time("%A")
    day_of_year = Time.yday
    this_year = Time("%Y")
    puts "Happy " + "#{today}" + "! It is the " + "#{day_of_year}" + " day of the year" + "#{this_year}"
    return self
end
def make_toast(color)
    puts "Making your toast #{color}!"
    return self
end
def make_milkshake(flavor)
    puts "Don\'t worry boss, my #{flavor} milkshake brings all the boys to the yard!"
    return self
end
def make_eggs(quantity)
    puts "Making you  #{quantity} eggs sir!"
    return self
end
end
```

but when I run the program via irb (`load 'personal_chef.rb', frank = PersonalChef.new, frank.make_milkshake('chocolate')`, etc,  everything works fine until I try to type `frank.good_morning` into irb, which gives  the following error message

> "NoMethodError: undefined method `Time' for #<PersonalChef:0x00000001b61808>
>       from personal_chef.rb:4:in`good_morning'
>       from (irb):3
>       from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `'

I tried substituting the `Date` method instead of `Time` and still encountered the same problem.

Thanks for reading, and hopefully for your forthcoming helpful advice! If there is more information that would be helpful to solve this issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The line of code

```
today = Time("%A")
```

uses `Time`, the `class`, as a method call, which explains the error.  I see that you are trying to extract the day name and the day of year from a time object, but passing the format string to `Time` isn't the way to do it.

You are looking for the [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) method.

Example:

```
>> today = Time.new()
=> 2013-06-19 21:58:34 -0700
>> today.strftime("%A")
=> "Wednesday"
>> today.strftime("%j")
=> "170"
```

Wednesday, the 170th day of the year.

Comment: Thank you so much Ray! You da' B!